# if conditions for array of linked list c++

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to access an array of linked lists. If there is no list at a certian index of the array of lists, I need to create a new node for the first element of that linked list. I know my if statment is not working properly,

```
  if ( arrayOfLists[label] == NULL )
```

My node struct is:

```
struct node {
        int x;
        node *next;
};
```

When I run my program I get stuck in an infinite while loop. That is in this function, the output of:

```
  cout << "x value " << hopper -> x << endl;
```

eventually becomes "x value 603," repeating forever.

```
 void Union(int largerLabel, int label, struct node *  arrayOfLists[], struct node * hopper) {
    cout << "union called" << endl;
            if ( arrayOfLists[label] == NULL )
            {
    //              cout << "if # 1" << endl;
                    arrayOfLists[label] = new node;
                    arrayOfLists[label] -> next = NULL;
                    arrayOfLists[label] -> x = largerLabel;
            }
            else {
    //              cout << "else # 1" << endl;
                    hopper = arrayOfLists[ label ];
                    while ( hopper -> next != NULL )
                    {
    //                      cout << "x value " << hopper -> x << endl;
                            if ( largerLabel == hopper -> x )
                            {
                                    cout << "return " << endl;
                                    return;
                            }
                            hopper = hopper -> next;
                    }
                    if ( arrayOfLists[largerLabel] != NULL )
                    {
    //                      cout << "if # 2" << endl;
                            hopper -> next = arrayOfLists[largerLabel];
                    }
                    else
                    {
    //                      cout << "else # 2" << endl;
                            hopper -> next = new node;
                            hopper = hopper -> next;
                            hopper -> x = largerLabel;
                            hopper -> next = NULL;
                    }
            }
    cout << "return" << endl;
    return;
    }
```

Comment: Don't. Use a `std::map<int, std::list<int>>`.

Comment: Generally in C++, one does not put spaces around `->`. Have you tried debugging and looking at variable values?

Comment: Okay lightness I will look into map, as I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @user3707614 Unless you are learning data structures by implementing them, you generally want to use standard container classes (`std::vector`, `std::map`, etc.),.

Comment: Do you mean with a special debugging software crashmstr? I have been looking at cout's of the x varriables they repeat often. Such as:      x value 10068
x value 10136
x value 10335
x value 10372
x value 10068
x value 10136
x value 10335
x value 10372
x value 10068

Comment: @crashmstr Yea I am learning while implementing.

Comment: @user3707614 have you used a debugger at all? It would let you set breakpoints, "watch" variables, and examine state as you step through the program line by line. In this case, you probably want to look at your loop condition, and make sure it is or is not changing as you expect.

Comment: @crashmstr No I have not used a debugger. I think I will try putting the code in codeblocks and debugging there.

Comment: @user3707614 - Looking at your code, it seems you want to add to the list only unique integers (why the return if an integer is already in the list?).  If this is the case, you would be way better off using `std::map<int,std::set<int>>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say what you try to achieve, but infinite execution clearly says that you have a loop in a list. For example this code:

```
                if ( arrayOfLists[largerLabel] != NULL )
                {
//                      cout << "if # 2" << endl;
                        hopper -> next = arrayOfLists[largerLabel];
                }
```

in case label == largerLabel and arrayOfLists[lable] != NULL definately creates a loop. It can make it in other conditions as well. This code does not look right.